# How to get a pointer on the return value of a function?

Tags: c, pointers, return-value

### The function

I'm using the function uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong) to convert a uint32_t to network byte order.

### What I want to do

I need to do calculations with the variable after converting it to network byte order:

```
//Usually I do calculate with much more variables and copy them into a much
// larger buff - to keep it understandable and simple I broke it down 
// to one calculation

uint32_t var = 1;
void* buff;

buff = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));

while(var < 5) {
    var = htonl(var);
    memcpy(buff, &var, sizeof(uint32_t));
    doSomethingWithBuff(buff);
    var++; // FAIL
}
```

### What I could do but ...

Actually I found a solutions for this problem already:

```
uint32_t var = 1, nbo;
void* buff;

buff = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));

while(var < 5) {
    nbo = htonl(var);
    memcpy(buff, &nbo, sizeof(uint32_t));
    doSomethingWithBuff(buff);
    var++;
}
```

The problem is that I waste memory with this solution because nbo is just used as a buffer.

### What I would prefer to do

It would be perfect if I could use the htonl() function within the memcpy() function.
memcpy() needs the 2nd value to be a void*. My Question is: How can I get the address of the return value of htonl()?

```
uint32_t var = 1;
void* buff;

buff = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));

while(var < 5) {
    memcpy(buff, (GET ADDRESS)htonl(var), sizeof(uint32_t));
    doSomethingWithBuff(buff);
    var++;
}
```

And if it is not possible because there "is no address of this variable": How does a function work that is returning a variable rather than a pointer to a variable?

Comment: Why do you want to get the address of a local variable from a function?

Comment: And you're not just using a spare `uint32_t` and passing its address to your function because... why ? (i.e. what on earth makes you think you need to dynamically allocate *anything* ??) You're losing `nbo` in your "What I could do but ... " example, so why not just pass `&nbo` to the function and get rid of alll the `malloc()` junk?

Comment: @WhozCraig The while() is usually much more complex - buff is much larger and I do copy much more variables into the buff ...
Uchia Itachi sorry but I don't understand what you meen ...

Comment: @Genius then show that code (or at least mention it in the question). What is shown here requires nothing of the kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Discussion about only one variable buffer**

---

I think you are doing the wrong micro-optimizations.

As **Uchia Itachi** points out, getting the address of the return value would be a bug.

Actually, if you are concerned about efficiency, the bottleneck is static storage. malloc() has memory overhead - in addition to the data that you store in static memory, there is metadata written. For example [here (scroll down to Implementation Details)](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/malloc.html) is explained how a clever minimal algorithm has overhead of only size_t for each allocation. And this is not even considering fragmentation.

memcpy() is a fast function, but also an overkill for a single number.

Therefore, I recommend using only the stack. Make buff a global integer variable. Then pass buff,s address to those, requireing a buffer. They won't notice the difference.

**Discussion about the modified question - large buffer with lots of writes and reads in the loop**

---

When a function returns (something), it pushes the value (or pointer to an object) in a register or on the stack. On the other hand, when a variable is declared, initialized and used, it resides either in a register or on the stack.

Do you notice the similarity? Optimizing compilers remove unneeded variables, they also create unnamed variables for internal use. For example, *the storage of a variable is reused after detecting that the variable is no longer referenced in this scope.*

Therefore, one should strive to write simple and readable code, and leave the details to the compiler. Meaning that your second example is perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you please do an example on how to replace the memcpy()?

Comment: I added a comment to my question - usually buff is much larger and I do much more calculation so I do need malloc() ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot be sure where the return value of a function will be put. Sometimes, the value is returned on the stack, other times, it may be in a register. There is no real difference between returning something versus returning a pointer in C. But it is good not to mess with local variables that are defined and accessible only in a different function. Doing so increases the chances of seg faults. Also, using &nbo is not a waste of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the issue "away" using a macro:

```
#define APPEND_TO_BUFFER( \
  buffer, \
  value, \
  type) 
  { \
    type tmpvar = (value); \
    memcpy((buffer), &tmpvar, sizeof(type)); \
  }

...

char * buff = <some valid memory address>;

uint32_t var = <some value>;
int i = <some other value>;

...

  APPEND_TO_BUFFER(buff, htonl(var), uint32_t); /* Append converted var to buffer as per OP. */
  APPEND_TO_BUFFER(buff+sizeof(uint32_t), i, int); /* Append another i right after var.  */

  doSomethingWithBuff(buff);
```